# Matplotlib with a single subplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting columns of a pandas dataframe in subplots. Which columns to plot is stored in an array, `an`. The below code works fine if `len(an)>1`, i.e. if I plot more than one graph,

```
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(an))
    for index, item in enumerate(an, start=0):
        gd.plot(ax=axs[index],x="Date",y=item)
```

but it fails with the error

> TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable

if `len(an)==1`.

Is it possible to make subplots work, if there is just a single plot to plot, or do I have to treat this case separately with an `if`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib: TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52273546/matplotlib-typeerror-axessubplot-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to matplotlib's documentation, the parameter "squeeze" solves your problem:

> **squeeze**: bool, optional, default: True
>
> - If True, extra dimensions are squeezed out from the returned array of Axes:
>
>   - if only one subplot is constructed (nrows=ncols=1), the resulting single Axes object is returned as a scalar.
>   - for Nx1 or 1xM subplots, the returned object is a 1D numpy object array of Axes objects.
>   - for NxM, subplots with N>1 and M>1 are returned as a 2D array.
> - If False, no squeezing at all is done: the returned Axes object is always a 2D array containing Axes instances, even if it ends up being
>     1x1.

So the solution to your problem would be:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,len(an),squeeze=False)
for index, item in enumerate(an, start=0):
    gd.plot(ax=axs[0,index],x="Date",y=item)
```

Comment: Thanks. I swapped indices around to have vertically stacked plots but your solution works perfectly. So I have: `fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(an),1,squeeze=False)` and  ` gd.plot(ax=axs[index,0],x="Date",y=item)` .

Comment: Your welcome @user1583209. As a friendly reminder. If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to mark it as an accepted answer. Not only does it help me, but other users who may have a similar question in the future.